# Can 'and' be used replaceable by 'or'?

Tags: conjunctions

[image: Source]
I think it should be

> Surrender it or face the consequences.

Also I am confused of a comma before 'or' used sometimes.

Comment: Your interpretation seems correct to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Surrender [it] **and** ... be spared [the consequences].
>   Surrender  it   **or**    ... face the consequences.

They are only equivalent because you're not just replacing *and* with *or* there: you're replacing *and be spared the consequences* with *or face the consequences*.

The two forms of 'paratactic conditional' have opposite meanings. *P **and** Q* means "If P then Q"; *P **or** Q* means "If **not** P, then Q".

> Stop and I'll shoot! *means "If you stop I will shoot"*.
>   Stop or I'll shoot! *means "If you don't stop I will shoot"*.

As for the comma between the clauses, it's optional: use it if it's needed to make the structure clear or to avoid ambiguity—or to mark a pause in speech.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Do that and I'll punch you.
> 2. Do that or I'll punch you.

Sentence (1) means:

- If you do that, I'll punch you.

Sentence (2) means:

- Unless you do that, I'll punch you.

In British English we wouldn't use a comma in sentences (1) or (2).